How do we determine the temperature of BEC by time-of-flight imaging?
I am studying atomic physics and I have a small question about the experimental realization in BEC experiment. When the temperature is way below the critical temperature, the condensation occurs and we can see there is an obvious spot at the center and the thermal cloud surrounds it. (like picture below)

Now if we do the time-of-flight imaging then what do the experimentalist measure to deduce the temperature of the condensation part? (I don't mean the surrounding thermal cloud but the condensate part.)

It's not difficult. Release the BEC and take pictures after some different times. Fit a bimodal distribution to it. The width vs time plot will give you the temperature.
Have a look here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9904034 (p.34)
This paper is standard for every experimentalist working in the field.

thank you for the reply. I have also studied this paper. The most confusing point for me is that the condensated particles are in the very central area and the expanding behaviour is totally different from the that of the thermal cloud. So according to this article(p.34) "The temperature of the gas can be determined from the shape of the spatial wings of the distribution ascribed to the thermal cloud." Why can the spatial wing of the thermal cloud determine the condense temperature in the center?

Temperature is a distribution of particle velocities. E.g. for a thermal cloud, it is a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. Knowing the shape allows you to determine the termperature

Thank you for your reply. When we get the image of the time-of-flight, how can we get the information of the distribution with respect to the velocity? Normally what we get from the time-of-flight is the number distribution with respect to the position.

This is also detailed in the Ketterle Paper.
For a thermal cloud, integrate/sum the image in x or y direction and fit a maxwell boltzmann distribution to it.

This is a partial answer since it's been a while since I have studied this stuff in detail.
First off, it is challenging to accurately measure the temperature of a BEC. One way to do it is as follows. From the images you show you can make a bimodal fit to the momentum distribution that you are measuring. From this you can estimate the condensate fraction. From the

condensate fraction
the total atom number
the trap frequencies

I believe you can estimate, using a simple model, the temperature of the BEC.
